# How to load configuration from .yaml file before executing all go test files?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I wrote a go test file in a package then run `go test ./...` to execute all tests.

The problem is some test need app config which is stored in .yaml file in project root dir. Normally when I run `main.go` file in root, it works well since the current working dir `os.Getwd()` will be the root dir. But when running test, the current working dir becomes the test file path which make the config file cannot be found.

I was thinking of 2 solution:

- Initialize config before for all tests
- Update the config init function to use to project root dir instead of current working dir

I tried searching but haven't found any solution yet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Generally, reading config files is bad practice in tests (in unit tests, in particular). Tests should _not_ depend on configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking about that. I just want to know if there's a solution to a problem like this. It would be ok if there isn't, I will figure another way. Thank you

Comment: There's always a way. You can do any amount of pre-test init you want. It just may not be very easy or maintainable :)

Comment: And of course, for certain types of integration or E2E tests, loading config can be perfectly appropriate. But that should be a minority of tests, in most cases.

Comment: But can I do it once for all test files? I've read about pre-test setup but seems that I have to do it for each test file.

Comment: You'll need to do that for each package, yes.  There is no way to handle this for all packages in Go, short of code generation, perhaps.

Comment: ah ok, thank you for your help. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a collection of tests to share logic/state, then I'd suggest looking at [TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main).

From there you can optionally pre-load alternative logic and make it available to all or a subset of your tests:

```
var (
    testConfig *Config // use this global config in tests
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

    // optional alternative config via ENV VAR `CONFIG`
    if path := os.Getenv("CONFIG"); path != "" {
        
        conf, err := LoadConfig(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to load config file %q : %v", path, err)
        }

        testConfig = &conf

    } else {
        testConfig = &DefaultConfig // no override - so use default config
    }

    // call flag.Parse() here if TestMain uses flags
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```